# at update record number of divs show based on record

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I'm going to insert the record I can insert multiple record. I've add more button when I click at add more it creates clone with he help of jquery here my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //alert("auction-company");
    var divLength = 1;
    var locationLength = 2;
    $("#addMore").on('click', function () {
        //alert("auction-company");
        var cloneObj = $('.toClone').clone().removeClass('toClone');
        $(cloneObj).attr('id', 'addLocations' + divLength);
        $(cloneObj).find('span[id="locationCounter"]').attr('id', 'locationCounter' + locationLength).html(locationLength);
        /* for element ids increment starting */
        $(cloneObj).find('input[id="auctionLocationName0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationName' + divLength).val('');
        $(cloneObj).find('input[id="auctionLocationAddress0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationAddress' + divLength).val('');
        $(cloneObj).find('input[id="auctionLocationCity0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationCity' + divLength).val('');
        $(cloneObj).find('select[id="auctionLocationState0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationState' + divLength).val('');
        $(cloneObj).find('input[id="auctionLocationZipcode0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationZipcode' + divLength).val('');
        $(cloneObj).find('input[id="auctionLocationPhone0"]').attr('id', 'auctionLocationPhone' + divLength).val('');
        /* for element ids increment ending */
        $(cloneObj).find('div[class="tools"] a[id="firstRowRemoveDisable"]').addClass('remove');
        $("#toAppend").append(cloneObj);
        divLength++;
        locationLength++;
    });
});
```

It is working fine but when I'm going for update using jquery ajax how can I show 2 divs and its record. jQuery ajax and `dataType` is `json`. here is my update code

```
var auctionComapnyLocation = data.auctionResponseArray;
for (var auctionCompanyLocationLoop = 0; auctionCompanyLocationLoop < auctionComapnyLocation.length; auctionCompanyLocationLoop++) {
    $("#addLocations" + auctionCompanyLocationLoop).show(); 

    var cloneObj = $("#addLocations" + auctionCompanyLocationLoop).clone();
    $(cloneObj).removeClass('toClone');
    $(cloneObj).find('div[class="tools"] a[id="firstRowRemoveDisable"]').addClass('remove');
    //$(cloneObj).find('span[id="locationCounter"]').attr('id', 'locationCounter' + auctionCompanyLocationLoop).html(auctionCompanyLocationLoop);
    $("#toAppend").append(cloneObj);
    //$("#auctionLocationName").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationName);
    /*$("#auctionLocationName").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationName);
    $("#auctionLocationAddress").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationAddress);
    $("#auctionLocationCity").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationCity);
    $("#auctionLocationState").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationState);
    $("#auctionLocationZipcode").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationZipcode);
    $("#auctionLocationPhone").val(data.auctionResponseArray.auctionLocationPhone);
    */

}
```

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle; it'll get your question answered **correctly** most of the time. And also, you must be more specific with what your question is **exactly**

Comment: Why is all the value assignment commented out?

Comment: now at edit I can see the the divs but there ids are 0 although I'm using loop variable but it didn't work, the id must be like 0 1 but it is showing 0 at both div `var cloneObj = $("#addLocations" + auctionCompanyLocationLoop).clone();`